# Is there anyway to remove Design (and Split) views from Visual Studio 2005/2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to find a way to disable Design / Split views from appearing in Visual Studio. I figure there's no way to completely disable it, but I still can't seem to find a way to remove the shortcut (F7), or remove the buttons from the bottom bar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best I found was:

for HTML/ASPX - Options -> HTML Designer -> start pages in source view

for XAML -> Options -> Text Editor -> XAML -> Misc -> Always open documents in full XAML view

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard shortcut is listed under View.ToggleDesigner.

I just want to be able to disable the Design view; the F7 shortcut is rather handy for swapping between source and code behind when doing web development.

Answer (score 1):

Short blog post here apparently has an answer for this problem
http://renaissauce.com/thoughts/visual-studio-2008-tip-remove-the-design-split-source-button-bar/

Comment: I Googled the actual blog post title and found this: http://renaissauce.com/post/Visual-Studio-2008-Tip-Remove-the-DesignSplitSource-button-bar.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to delete the keyboard assignment for F7 in the Keyboard Customization screen. All hotkey assignments are customizable AFAIK.

I doubt there's any way to get rid of the buttons on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a solution for XAML](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2009/01/29/life-changer-xaml-tip-for-visual-studio.aspx)